# Custom domain SMTP via Postfix via Amazon EC2 / SES

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-ses

Is it possible for Postfix to transport mail differently by specific domain?

I.e.
domainxyz.com - uses the default settings to mail from postfix
domain55zy.com - needs to use a relay server @ 123xyzcom
thisdomain.com - needs to use relay server @ 555zyx.com

I've modified transport as i.e.:

```
domain.tld process33:
```

Then in master.cf I've added:

```
process33        unix    -  -   n   -   1   smtp
```

then in main.cf I've added:

```
process33_relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
process33_sasl_auth_enable = yes
process33_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
process33_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sas2_passwd
process33_use_tls = yes
process33_tls_security_level = encrypt
process33_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
process33_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

However none of this is working.. I've set mydestination to the local URL; yet it does not work.  This needs to catch outgoing email from a specific hosted site and route it through Amazon's SES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by:

1. Utilizing: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps - by catching the email sender and forwarding into a unix socket called "server33"
2. Utilizing: transport_maps to push into DOMAINXYZ.com:25
3. Adding the sasl / password map for this transport by appending "server33" before the parameters.